# SIGSEGV whilst attempting to read array

Tags: c++, ncurses, dynamic-arrays

I've done some research on this and after finding not much that's helpful, then exhausting all my options with trying to fix this, I've now decided to ask the Stack Overflow community for advice. I just cannot figure out for the life of me why I get a SIGSEGV when attempting to use `form = new_form(field);`.

The function in question is this one:

```
void GkForms::formNavLabel(std::shared_ptr<WINDOW> display, FIELD *field[], std::vector<char *> fieldNames, const size_t &fieldCount)
{
try {
    // Clear the WINDOW
    assert(display != NULL);
    wclear(display.get());

    // Initialization options
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(display.get(), TRUE);

    int formWinRows = 0;
    int formWinCols = 0;
    int subWinRows = 0;
    int subWinCols = 0;
    int ch = 0;
    static FORM *form;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < fieldCount; ++i) {
        if (fieldNames.at(i) == nullptr) {
            throw std::runtime_error(gettext("There has been an internal error with creating the form."));
        }
    }

    // Initialize the fields
    for (size_t i = 0; i < fieldCount; ++i) {
        field[i] = makeLabelActive(i, 0, fieldNames.at(i));
        assert(field[i] != NULL);
    }

    // Set field options
    for (size_t i = 0; i < fieldCount; ++i) {
        set_field_back(field[i], COLOR_PAIR(15));
        set_field_fore(field[i], COLOR_PAIR(16));
        field_opts_on(field[i], O_VISIBLE);
        field_opts_on(field[i], O_ACTIVE);
        field_opts_off(field[i], O_EDIT);
    }

    // Create the form and post it
    form = new_form(field);
```

And the code implementing the use of this function is here:

```
            std::vector<xmlConfig::Servers> xmlData = data_serverMenu(xmlCfgFile);
            unsigned short lineCount = 0;
            unsigned short linesPerPage = (subScrollYSize - (borderSize * 2));
            std::vector<char *> output;
            short pages = (linesPerPage / xmlData.size());
            short curPage = 1;
            int ch;

            for (size_t i = 0; i < xmlData.size(); ++i) {
                if (i < linesPerPage) {
                    i = (i * curPage);
                    std::stringstream ss;
                    ss << " [ " << xmlData.at(i).serverProtocol.c_str() << " ] " << xmlData.at(i).serverName.c_str() << " ";
                    output.push_back(const_cast<char *>(ss.str().c_str()));
                    ++lineCount; // Do not get rid of this!
                }
            }

            FIELD *fields[(lineCount + 1)];

            for (unsigned short i = 0; i < (lineCount + 1); ++i) {
                fields[i] = new FIELD();
                if (i == (lineCount + 1)) {
                    fields[i] = 0;
                }
            }

            std::unique_ptr<GkForms> gkForms (new GkForms());
            gkForms->formNavLabel(display, fields, output, lineCount);
```

The code is quite messy at the moment as it's in the midst of development/experimentation but as you might notice, I'm implementing a NCurses application where the C++ interfaces with the C code. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

P.S. I've decided to include this helper function also, just in case it's needed to diagnose the problem.

```
/**
 * @brief GkForms::makeLabelActive creates form 'labels' that can be selected and interacted with
 * @author Phobos Aryn'dythyrn D'thorga
 * @param frow      Position on the y-axis (NOTE: it is reversed, a possible bug?)
 * @param fcol      Position on the x-axis (NOTE: it is reversed, a possible bug?)
 * @param label     What you wish for the label to display as text
 * @return          Returns a complete FIELD object, ready to be used by the NCurses
 * forms library
 */
FIELD *GkForms::makeLabelActive(int frow, int fcol, char *label)
{
    FIELD *f = new_field(1, (int) strlen(label), frow, fcol, 0, 0);
    if (f) {
        set_field_buffer(f, 0, label);
        set_field_opts(f, (int) ((unsigned) field_opts(f) & O_ACTIVE));
    }

    return f;
}`
```

Comment: `static FORM *form;`? Why is this `static`?  And what is `FORM`?

Comment: Details about `FORM` can be found here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/forms.html

In code I've previously written where FORM was more well behaved, I had to make it static or it gave a SIGSEGV for some reason there also. I still do not understand why.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
output.push_back(const_cast<char *>(ss.str().c_str()));
```

the pointer

```
ss.str().c_str()
```

becomes invalid at the end of the statement.

You need to either allocate a copy dynamically, or start using `std::string`.

There are other issues as well;

```
fields[i] = new FIELD();
if (i == (lineCount + 1)) {
     fields[i] = 0;
}
```

is a memory leak if the condition is ever true, for instance.
And casting away `const` should not be done without serious consideration of the consequences.

Comment: I just noticed the problem with `output.push_back(const_cast<char *>(ss.str().c_str()));` also whilst debugging, as it would throw an exception. Cheers too about the memory leak, I didn't notice that one :) There's a lot I don't know, as I've never had a formal education with regard to computer programming. I'm completely self-taught over the latter part of a year.